# How do i add different font colors inside a text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text field where someone can type in a string.

Depending on what the user types in this string i would like to change to color of specific words. Similar to syntax highlighting.

For example a user could type:

```
something::anotherthing
```

which should be translated into

```
<span class=color1>something</span><span class=color2>::</span>anotherthing
```

How would that be possible inside a text field, as html will not be translated there ?

Comment: It is too broad. I would advise you to go and use an already existing plugin for this. Edit it if it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I give you an answer with a demo, pleas visit my demo and test :: and then you will understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

use the [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute on a div or other supporting element. this is how most online html editors work.  You will get built-in support for selecting a region of text and changing its color and other properties, as well as undo/redo support.

[live working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3wp816mh/):

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    change the color!
</div>


<button>
    red
</button>
<button>
    blue
</button>
<button>
    green
</button>
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('button').click(function(){
document.execCommand('ForeColor', false, $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: by the way, keep in mind that when you use content-editable, the user will be able to insert all sorts of html into here, he can even paste images and there will be and image tag in there. you can manage this by handling paste and keystroke events. It's quite complex so I wont go into details unless its requested.

Comment: I didn’t vote this down, but this is not really an answer to the question asked. It might be an answer to what the OP really wants, but answers should be evaluated on the basis of how they address the question that was actually asked.

Comment: Jukka, I see your point. Sandersen asked to do this inside of a text field. Since this is not possible, I have suggested something similar that is possible. I believe that this contributes something of value to the question.  I up-voted your answer because it does indeed address the question in a more specific manner.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot style parts of the value of text field differently from the rest of that value, assuming that “text field” means `<input type=text>`. The reason is that the value of such a field is by definition plain text. It is not even content of the element, just its value, stored in the DOM, but there is no way to inject HTML elements into it.

If you actually want to create an input text editor, you should first search for existing questions and answers on that topic and then, if problems remain, post a question about specific problems that you encounter using editable elements.